# Linking user uid to firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently making an app in react-native and would like to link userid generated from firebase authentication to user information in my firebase database.

```
{
  users:useruid:{
                  //Storing other user information
               }
}
```

I am retrieving the uid from auth and creating a new child for the users like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

  console.log(user)

  if(user){

    user.getToken().then((userid) => {
      //Set the initial state
      firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(userid).set({
        'uid': userid,
        'businessName': business,
        'street address': street,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'zipcode': zipcode,
        'productGroup': 0,
        'pom': 0,
        'som': 0,
        'inventory': 0,
        'reporting_and_analytics': 0,
        'accounting': 0
      })

      dispatch({type: types.REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS})

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.message)
      dispatch({type: types.REGISTER_BUSINESS_FAILURE, error});
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log("ERROR: Registration error")
  }
});

 }
```

I am getting the error: Invalid path with regards to the uid generated. Any help. I have checked documentation on firebase and similar questions related to this but still getting the same error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v10sT.png)

Comment: use `uid` instead of token, like `firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(user.uid)`

Comment: @cherniv I am getting the same error with user.uid. Also on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) user.getToken() is recommended rather than user.uid.

Comment: @Cherniv user.uid works. After several retries, it worked. user.getToken() generates a token with some characters that cannot be used on a firebase path. [firebase Invalid Characters](https://zapier.com/help/common-problems-firebase/)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. I realise your post is a couple of years old - so maybe things have changed, but I can't get this approach to work. are you still using in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(userid)
```

is essentially the same as saying `//users//userid` because of the way `child()` works, which is obviously an incorrect path.

Instead lose the `/` before and after `users`. Try:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(userid)
```

The `child()` methods will form the correct path.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. However, I did not encounter any issues with having the '/ ' before and after the name of the node when writing to firebase and specifying the full path using: firebase.database.ref([name of the full path of node you are trying to access]). There were issues though when using child() method and including slashes.